# find two consecutive words/strings with regex expression java (including punctuation)

Tags: java, regex, cpu-word, punctuation

I want to check wheter a string is containing two words/string directly followed in a specific order.
The punctuation should also be included in the word/string. (i.e. **"word"** and **"word."** should be handeled as **different words**).

As an example:

```
    String word1 = "is";
    String word1 = "a";
    String text = "This is a sample";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(someregex+"+word1+"someregex"+word2+"someregex");
    System.out.println(p.matcher(text).matches());
```

This should print out **true**.

With the following variables, it should also print true.

```
    String word1 = "sample.";
    String word1 = "0END";
    String text = "This is a sample. 0END0";
```

But the latter should return false when setting word1 = "sample" (without punctuation).

Does anyone have an idea how the regex string should look like (i.e. what i should write instead of "someregex" ?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just splitting on whitespace, try:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)" + Pattern.quote(word1) + "\\s+" + Pattern.quote(word2) + "(\\s|$)");
```

**Explaination**

`(\\s|^)` matches any whitespace before the first word, or the start of the string

`\\s+` matches the whitespace between the words

`(\\s|$)` matches any whitespace after the second word, or the end of the string

`Pattern.quote(...)` ensures that any regex special characters in your input strings are properly escapes.

You also need to call `find()`, not `match()`. `match()` will only return true if the *whole* string matches the pattern.

**Complete example**

```
String word1 = "is";
String word2 = "a";
String text = "This is a sample";

String regex =
    "(\\s|^)" + 
    Pattern.quote(word1) +
    "\\s+" +
    Pattern.quote(word2) + 
    "(\\s|$)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
System.out.println(p.matcher(text).find());
```

Comment: Hi Jamie!
Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately this isn't working..

  String text = "This is a sample sentence."; 
  String string = "sample";
  String string2 = "sentence.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s|^" + string + "\\s" + string2 + "\\s|$");
System.out.println(p.matcher(text).matches());

is printing out false...
as well as setting string="is" and string2="a" what seems odd for me...

Comment: closer, but unfortunately not working...
trying  word1 = "a"; and word2 = "sample.NoSpace"; sould return false instead of true... :(

Comment: I don't follow your last example, what are the values of `word1`, `word2` and `text` that don't work?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't update everythin from your edit (without the Pattern(quote)).
With your answer now and the "find()" call, everything just works perfectly!
Thank you very much!!

Comment: One more update, to allow multiple spaces between your two words.

Comment: or just trim the string before calling the regex ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the two words with a whitespace and use that as the regexp.
the only thing, you have to do, is to replace "." with "." so the point does not match as any character.

```
String regexp = " " + word1 + " " + word2 + " ";
regexp = regexp.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\.");
```